# Howto return a future when pushing to a thread pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, future

I try to push a task with return value to a thread pool:

```
template<class Function>
auto enqueue(Function&& f)
{
    using ReturnType = std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<Function>()>;
    std::promise<ReturnType> ret_promise;
    auto fut = ret_promise.get_future();
    auto task = UniqueFunction<void()>(
       [do_it = std::move(f), ret = std::move(ret_promise)]() mutable {
           ret.set_value(do_it());
       });
    {
        std::lock_guard lock{m_mtx};
        m_tasks.push(std::move(task));
        m_cv.notify_one();
    }
return fut;
}
```

And the loop looks like this:

```
void performTasks()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{m_mtx};
        m_cv.wait(lock, [this]() { return !m_tasks.empty() || m_terminate; });
        if(!m_tasks.empty())
        {
            auto task = std::move(m_tasks.front());
            m_tasks.pop();
            lock.unlock();
            task();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Helgrind complains about data race when trying to wait for the result:

> Possible data race during read of size 8 at 0x5DFB618 by thread #1
>
> This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #2

Is this a false positive or is there some problem with the implementation above?

Comment: please post a full working example.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a data race in your code. The problem may be somewhere else. Like modifying `m_terminate` without proper synchronization.

It may also be a false positive. According to [documentation](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html), Helgrind detects synchronization errors in programs that use the POSIX pthreads threading primitives. So Helgrind may fail to recognize that a particular piece of code is properly synchronized if it does not use pthread primitives.

Synchronization mechanisms like `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable`, `std::atomic` etc may or may not use pthread primitives in their implementation. In particular, `std::atomic`s most likely do not.

I advise you use [ThreadSanitizer](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) instead of Helgrind for detecting threading errors.

Comment: When running the code using ThreadSanitizer, there is no problem. So yes, it is std::atomic. std::mutex and std::condition_variable use pthread under the hood.

Comment: is `m_terminate` an atomic bool?

Comment: No, but guarded by the same mutex. But futures use atomic operations when fetching the data. And thus, it will fail in helgrind.